# Python Interactive Brokers ibapi

Tags: python, class, superclass

I am having trouble using and incrementing the "orderId" for each stock order using modified IB example code. I have a method that produces nextValidId within the class and prints it to stdout but I am not sure how to access the defined property (self.nextValidOrderId) that is created in my main() program body.  I am able to instantiate the EWrapper and EClient Class and place orders (If I manually input the orderId). In example code I hard code it to 126.  I thought I would be able to use the following in my main() program body.
"orderId = app.nextValidOrderId"  but it does not work.

```
`__author__ = 'noone'

from Testbed.OrderSamples import OrderSamples
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *

class OrderApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)

    def error(self,reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
        print("Error:",reqId," ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    # This is the initial response after connection to TS from the API providing next available OrderID
    @iswrapper        
    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
    super().nextValidId(orderId)

    print("setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
    self.nextValidOrderId = orderId

    def contractDetails(self, reqId:int, contractDetails:ContractDetails):
        print("contractDetails: ", reqId, " ", contractDetails)

def main():
    app=OrderApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1",7497,0)

    ## Build the contract object to be passed to the order Method

    stock_contract = Contract()
    stock_contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
    stock_contract.secType = 'STK'
    stock_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
    stock_contract.currency = 'USD'
    stock_contract.primaryExchange = 'NASDAQ'

    # reqID must be provided to the Order. This method gets the reqID from IB DB's
    app.reqContractDetails(10, stock_contract)

    try:
        # Now place the order in Paper Money Account
        app.placeOrder(126, stock_contract, OrderSamples.LimitOrder("BUY", 50, 12))

    except:
        raise

    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not syntactically correct. It should have indentation as below

```
@iswrapper        
def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
    super().nextValidId(orderId)

    print("setting nextValidOrderId: %d" % orderId)
    self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
```

Also you are not importing the function decorator iswrapper

```
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper
```

Hope this helps